# Counterpart to -application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios, uiapplicationdelegate

iOS SDK 4.2 includes a new `UIApplicationDelegate` method called [`application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:). It is a replacement for `application:handleOpenURL:` and offers more information about the calling application: not only do we get the bundle identifier of the calling app, but also, in the `annotation` argument,

> A property-list object supplied by the source application to communicate information to the receiving application.

Great, this should offer a lot of opportunities for a more direct interaction between multiple third-party apps!

The only problem is: how do I invoke this mechanism on the side of the calling app? `-[UIApplication openURL:]` seems unchanged and does not offer any way to pass a property list along with the URL. Do you know how a calling app could do that with iOS SDK 4.2?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use the new Document Interaction classes, specifically you can send this data via the `annotation` property of `UIDocumentInteractionController`. See also:

- [UIDocumentInteractionController Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009304)
- [Document Interaction Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010403)

Comment: Thanks, bosmacs. That makes the method somewhat less useful.

Comment: Probably because UIDocumentInteractionController is very strict about the UI that is used to send the document to the other app.