# UIApplicationDelegate: Is there any documented use of `annotation` by other applications?

Tags: objective-c, ios

When a document is opened in an application from another app, the file name passed into `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` is pretty nonsensical for display purposes.  The [annotation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3aopenURL%3asourceApplication%3aannotation%3a) portion of this message should contain an `NSDictionary` containing user information, like a friendly file name.  Since the structure of this field is pretty loose, **is there any site that has attempted to aggregate what different apps use when passing that meta-data to other applications?**

I realize that trying to account for all apps would likely be an exercise in futility, but being able to handle a few popular applications would be useful to try and accommodate.

Comment: Did you find out how to pass info to the method using the (id)annotation ? I know how to pass info in the URL but how about the annotation?

Comment: @NicolasManzini I have not yet found any documentation on it.

Comment: @NicolasManzini See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259383.

Answer (score 0):

http://handleopenurl.com/scheme, and a few more at http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes.

Comment: I am aware of this project, but it is for application *schemes*, not the `annotation` of the 'Open In' API.