# Pass NSDictionary or a String from one App to another App iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, nsstring

I have to send data which is present in an dictionary from one application to another application, which has to used over there.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure about how to do it but I think you might need to use the Custom URL Schemes for that. Here is a link that can help you [register your URL Scheme and then using it.](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

Answer (score 0):

At least you can pass it as a string parameter of custom url (like `thesecondapp://data_string_goes_here`) and then parse it from within the app you pass it to

See how to encode `NSData` to `NSString` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-utf-8-encoded-nsdata-to-nsstring).

**EDIT:** You should also take a look at [application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:) method implementation examples. It could be a bit more sophisticated but it seems to be more 'native' than just passing a raw string.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259383/counterpart-to-applicationopenurlsourceapplicationannotation) is the info how to call the 'counterpart' of this method from another app.